# Объясните что делает код

Tags: java

```
public int mix(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: если хоть какие-нибудь предположения? :)

Comment: Открывает дверь в параллельную вселенную, очевидно же

Comment: Он выводит минимальное из двух чисел. Только я не понимаю что тут делает  двоеточие и знак вопроса,

Comment: загугли "тернарный оператор в Java"

Comment: @Andrew это называется тернарный оператор. Это основа языка программирования

Comment: А почему бы не дописать main и попробовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно Вас смутил [тернарный оператор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) `логическое выражение ? выражение 1 : выражение 2`. Можно заменить через `if else' чтобы было понятно:

```
public int mix(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Очевидно что это нахождение минимума.